# Street scene (with car if possible) with permissive license

Tags: images, 3d

This might be off-topic perhaps (since it's not quite a software), but I'm looking for a **blender (.blend file that I can tweak) street scene** with a road and possibly a car (some road signs and horizontal signs would be great.. crosswalk and things like that).

I'd like to use that for some demo of my commercial software (I'd reconstruct some basic positions of the car and do screenshots and such) so it must have a permissive license that I can use to do so.

Free is obviously better.

Comment: So, you want a video? Or a tool to generate videos from 3D models/scenarios, plus the 3D model?

Comment: I'm editing the question, I'm looking for a .blend scene

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets like howtos, manuals, [multi-media content](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/935/185). If you're looking for data, our sister-site [Open Data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be worth checking with.

Comment: Actually this sounds like a question for the Blender SO site http://blender.stackexchange.com/